# What's the difference between `git config` and `git push --set-upstream`

Tags: git, git-push, git-config

### Question

What's the difference between:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:yourname/yourproject.git
$ git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
$ git push
```

and:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:yourname/yourproject.git
$ git push origin master -u
```

Is the second version simply newer and shorter than the first version, or are there other differences?

### Background Research

As of Git 1.7.0, you can use the `--set-upstream` option with `git push`. According to the `git push` manual:

> ```
> -u, --set-upstream
>     For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream
>     (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) and other commands. For
>     more information, see branch.<name>.merge in git-config(1).
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, these are very different.  The first config setting, `remote.<name>.push` sets a default refspec for pushing if no other refspec is specified.  By default, doing `git push origin` will push every branch to a branch with a matching name so long as a branch with that name already existed on the remote.  After doing:

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

... you will find that `git push origin` will just push `master` to `master`.

The other command you quote, `git push -u origin master`, sets two different config options if the push is successful:

- `branch.master.remote` is set to `origin`
- `branch.master.merge` is set to `refs/heads/master`

These essentially say that `master` in `origin` should be regarded as the default "upstream" branch of your `master` branch.  Their most obvious effect is to provide a default action for `git pull` when you are on `master`, but are also used in a variety of other situations, such as providing the helpful message at the top of `git status` that tells you where `master` is compared to `origin/master`.  These settings are *not*, however, used to inform the default action of `git push` and `git push origin` unless you have also set the config option `push.default` to `tracking` (or `upstream` in recent versions).

So, as a very approximate summary, setting `remote.<name>.push` affects the default action of `git push`, while `git push -u origin master` sets config options that usually just affect the action of `git pull`.