# How to push a local branch to a directory of remote branch?

Tags: git, directory, branch

For instance:

I have a local repo branch 'master', and a remote repo branch 'r-master' with a directory 'dir1', I'd like to push 'master' to 'r-master/dir1' and making 'master' to keep track of  'r-master/dir1', is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branches and directories are two separate concepts in Git (as oppose to SVN where directories represents branches or tag: See "[Git - Store branches in separate local directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101270/git-store-branches-in-separate-local-directories/5101286#5101286)").

So you can push `master` to `r-master`, but not to `r-master/dir1`

```
git push -u origin master:r-master
```

(with `-u` or `--set-upstream` if you need tracking: see

- "[What exactly does the “`u`” do? “`git push -u origin master`” vs “`git push origin master`”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)"
- "[What's the difference between `git config` and `git push --set-upstream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739181/whats-the-difference-between-git-config-and-git-push-set-upstream)")