# Facing problems while executing git status

Tags: git, git-push

I am facing a problem while using the `git status`. I get this output:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

At first the commit and push for readme(README.md) worked perfectly. How do I solve this?

Comment: when i run the git status command, i get that output above...

Answer (score 2):

You solve it by pushing it to master again:

```
git push
or, if your master branch wasn't tracking origin/master already
git push -u origin master
```

(See on that "tracking" business "[What's the difference between `git config` and `git push --set-upstream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739331/6309)" and "[hat exactly does the “`u`” do? “`git push -u origin master`” vs “`git push origin master`”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697750/what-exactly-does-the-u-do-git-push-u-origin-master-vs-git-push-origin-ma)"

The only time when git push doesn't solve that situation is when you need to do a git fetch in order to update the origin SHA1 that your local repo has in store.
See "[`git: Your branch is Ahead by X commits`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323933/6309)".

Comment: I tried the git push -u origin master but gives the same error

Comment: @user1984266 and `git fetch origin`, followed by `git status`?