# git config: "remote.origin.push" vs "push.default"

Tags: git

How does the following command:

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

relate to the following command:

```
git config push.default <option>
```

(either with the `--local`  or `--global` option)

where `<option>`  is one of:

```
nothing
matching
upstream (formerly tracking)
current
simple
```

?

I think I understand the second config command, but I don't understand how the first command conditions/relates to the second. Here are some references that provide context behind this question:

- [Warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in Git 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/warning-push-default-is-unset-its-implicit-value-is-changing-in-git-2-0)
- [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/git-push-current-branch)
- [What's the difference between `git config` and `git push --set-upstream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739181/whats-the-difference-between-git-config-and-git-push-set-upstream)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run:

```
git push origin ...
```

whatever is set in `remote.origin.push` overrides whatever is set in `push.default`.  More generally, if `remote.name.push` is not set (here *`name`* is `origin`), git falls back on `push.default`, and then if that is also not set, it falls back on the built-in defaults as described in your links.

(**Edit:** as noted in [Breaking Benjamin's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504544/git-config-remote-origin-push-vs-push-default/19504666?noredirect=1#comment87519950_19504666) and my reply to it, if there *is* a `...` part that contains at least one refspec, the refspec overrides `remote.origin.push`.  So `remote.origin.push` applies only when you name `origin` explicitly or implicitly on the command line *and* omit any and all refspecs on the command line as well.  For example, `git push` with no arguments that discovers `origin`, or `git push origin` with no additional arguments, has Git look up your `remote.origin.push` setting and use it; but `git push origin xyz` *does not* use your `remote.origin.push` setting.  Of course the `...` part above can include more flags, so the correct question at this point is whether the `...` part contains any refspecs.)

Note that:

```
git config --local na.me value
```

means the same thing as without `--local`.  When setting values (as here) the `--local`, `--global`, and `--file filename` options control where the value is set, but `--local` is the default.

(When fetching values:

```
git config na.me
```

[or `git config --get` or `git config --get-all` or `git config --get-regexp`], the `--local`, etc, options restrict where git will read from, and without one it reads from *all* of them, with the "most local" overriding a "less local" if something is set in more than one place.)

Comment: Thanks! - When you said `git push origin ...`, the `...` would be the  branch name (if provided), correct?

Comment: Yes (or arbitrary refspecs, e.g., `refs/tags/foo`, `:refs/deleteme`, etc).

Comment: @torek , if I have mentioned `git push origin branchName` , then it will get resolved to `git push origin branchName:refs/heads/branchName`. how will then `remote.origin.push` come in picture ?

Comment: The `git push` documentation states that `remote.<remote>.push` comes into play only when you run `git push <remote>` without a `<refspec>` part. If you *do* supply a `<refspec>` part, an empty destination part means to repeat the source part. Note, however, that an *unqualified* reference as in the `xyz` part of `git push origin xyz` does not necessarily translate to a *branch* name. One thing not clear to me is how it *does* translate in all cases (e.g., if you have both a branch `xyz` and a tag `xyz` but the remote has only a tag `xyz`).