# How to upload my files in github repository with command?

Tags: git, laravel, github

I have created a repository named [amarjobs](https://github.com/chonchol/amajobs).

There is no file now.
I want to upload my working file in this repository.
I have done some step:

```
 git init
 git remote add origin url
 git pull 
 git push origin master
```

But its throws an error.I am beginner with git.
I have searched but i do not get satisfied answer for my problem.
Could anyone solve my problem?

**Error:**

[image: This is the error]

Thanks.

Comment: You may have a look at the github guide if you haven't already: https://help.github.com/categories/managing-remotes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant push since there are changes in the remote branch which you do not have.
You can simply execute `git pull` before the push and it will fix this issue.

---

Follow those steps and you will be able to push your code to github:

```sh
# Create a git repository in the folder
git init

# add the remote url
git remote add origin git@github.com:chonchol/amajobs.git

# add your code to the repository
git add .

# commit your code
git commit -m "Message..."

# now once you have your code committed updated your branch with the remote code
git pull 

# now once you have the commit message of the merge - commit and push
git push origin master
```

Comment: not working take a look all procedure http://s24.postimg.org/7ptjofuth/Untitled.png

Comment: I see your problem, you have an old version of git. do this: `git pull origin master` and it will work.

Comment: You are using old version of git. the pull behaviors was changes in git v2.0. read more about it in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666709/default-set-of-refspec-for-git-push/36669881#36669881

Comment: Worked after adding the branch name?

Comment: Yes, its working.Thanks.I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Cool, glad to help, its better if you will update your git client to the latest version, once updated you will not longer need to add branch name after the `git pull`

Comment: Ok, i will do it.Thanks.