# Is there a Git alias for the remote tracking branch?

Tags: git

I know you can refer to the tip of the current branch in Git with the name `HEAD`.

Is there some sort of equivalent for referring to the tip of the remote tracking branch of the current branch?

Just so I don't have to type out `remote/current-branch` if there's something shorter.

Comment: [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@{upstream}` or just `@{u}`, with a branch name in front if you're not referring to your current checkout.

Comment: Would [`@{push}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36671530/6309) be of interest here?

Comment: Yes, in some settings, `@{push}` and `@{upstream}` might be set on different branches/remotes. (But I too use `@{u}` in most "normal" cases as a handy shortcut)

Comment: `@{U}` (capital U) also works. (For those who are too lazy to release and then repress the shift key. You know who you are.)